# What is the min IAM role required to create Azure Policy and Blueprint

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-policy

I have contributor access to a subscription. But i am not able to create Azure Policy and assign it to a particular resource group under the subscription. What is the role i needed to be assigned to if i need to create an Azure Policy and apply it to a subscription or a management group level.

Answer (score 2):

According to my research, many Built-in roles grant permission to Azure Policy resources. The **Resource Policy Contributor role** includes most Azure Policy operations. **Owner** has full rights. Both **Contributor** and **Reader** can use all read Azure Policy operations, but **Contributor** can also trigger remediation. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview#rbac-permissions-in-azure-policy)

According to your need, you can try to use  **Resource Policy Contributor role**
[image]

Besides, you also can try to create [custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) to meet your needs. Azure Policy has several permissions in two Resource Providers : [Microsoft.Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftauthorization) and [Microsoft.PolicyInsights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftpolicyinsights)

Answer (score 0):

You will require **"Owner"** role to create Policy Definitions and Policy Assignments.

Please check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) which describes the Owner and Contributor roles and what are the Actions and NotActions for these roles.

[image]